# Require input to be selected for pickerInput

Tags: r, input, shiny

How can I require that a user selects an input from a `pickerInput`?

Here is a basic example:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    width = 4,
      pickerInput(inputId = "fruit", 
                  label = "Fruits", 
                  choices = c("Apple", "Mango", "Pear", "Orange"),
                  options = list(`actions-box` = T, 
                                 `none-selected-text` = "Please make a selection!"),
                  multiple = T)
        ))
server <- function(input, output) {
   output$res <- renderPrint({
   input$fruit
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there an option I can add when I create the `pickerInput` menu that sets it so that the menu will always require input?

Comment: `req(input$fruit)` might help as the first line inside `output$res`.

Comment: You could just have a `selected=` inside the `pickerInput` that way it initializes on a choice, therefore no choice is not an option?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply update it, we can also add a popup indicating that at least 1 elements has to be selected

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

mychoices <- c("Apple", "Mango", "Pear", "Orange")

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    width = 4,
    pickerInput(inputId = "fruit", 
                label = "Fruits", 
                choices = mychoices,
                options = list(`actions-box` = T, `none-selected-text` = "Please make a selection!",selected = mychoices[1]),
                multiple = T)
  ),
  column(4,textOutput("res"))

)
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  data <- eventReactive(input$fruit,{
    if(is.null(input$fruit)){
      updatePickerInput(session,"fruit",choices = mychoices,selected = mychoices[1])
      showNotification("At least 1 should be selected", duration = 2,type = c("error"))
    }
    input$fruit
  },ignoreNULL = F)

  output$res <- renderPrint({
    req(data())
    data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If I am reading this properly it tells the user they need to select a value but then chooses the first value as a default?

Comment: What if I just wanted to re-ask the User to pick instead of default picking something. In my full code I use the UI to read in a file so I can't default to any value (unless I default to All values).